# How to test static call to PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...) in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, unit-testing, broadcastreceiver

I'm really lost on this problem. I did build the following BroadcastReceiver

```
package ch.pas.smslistenerservice.receiver;

import ch.pas.smslistenerservice.service.SMSListenerService;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class Resend extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static String logTag = "ch.pas.smslistenerservice.resend";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) { return; }

        Log.i(logTag, "Resend received");

        PendingIntent pIntent = getPendingIntent(context);
        if(pIntent != null) { 
            Log.d(logTag, "Canceling intent");
            pIntent.cancel(); 
        }

        Log.d(logTag, "Starting service...");
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, SMSListenerService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(SMSListenerService.EXTRA_TYPE, SMSListenerService.TYPE_RESEND);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context) {
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
                new Intent("ch.pas.smslistenerservice.RESEND"), 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    }
}
```

I tried to test the if statement and I would love to test if the PendingIntent object get the cancel message.

```
if(pIntent != null) { 
    Log.d(logTag, "Canceling intent");
    pIntent.cancel(); 
 }
```

What I tried was:

1. Factor out the method where the pending intent is retrieved and then use mockito to mock the returned PendingIntent. This didn't work out because Mockito can not mock final class (like PendingIntent).
2. Use PowerMock to mock the static call PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...) but this didn't work out because PowerMock can not be run on Android and if I run this test on JVM I get a RuntimeException with "Stub!" because I'm extending the BroadcastReceiver which works only Android.

I know that in that case it makes not too much sense to test this because there is not much logic to test in the if statement but what if there is more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this problem by using a combination of PowerMock, Mockito and Robolectric (<= this was the missing variable). Used Robolectric to shadow (mock) the static call to PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...) and to inject a mocked PendingIntent.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.robolectric.*;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import ch.pas.smslistenerservice.receiver.Resend;
import ch.pas.smslistenerservice.service.SMSListenerService;

@Config(shadows=CustomShadowPendingIntent.class)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ResendTest {
    Resend receiver;
    Context context;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
        pendingIntent = PowerMockito.mock(PendingIntent.class);
        receiver = new Resend();
    }

    @Test
    public void testStartServiceWithoutExistingPendingIntent() {
        CustomShadowPendingIntent.setPendingIntent(null);

        Intent intent = new Intent("ch.pas.smslistenerservice.RESEND");
        receiver.onReceive(context, intent);      

        ArgumentCaptor<Intent> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Intent.class);
        verify(context).startService(argument.capture());
        Intent capturedIntent = argument.getValue();
        assertFalse(-1 == capturedIntent.getIntExtra(SMSListenerService.EXTRA_TYPE, -1));
        assertEquals(SMSListenerService.TYPE_RESEND, 
                capturedIntent.getIntExtra(SMSListenerService.EXTRA_TYPE, -1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testStartServiceWithExistingPendingIntent() {
        CustomShadowPendingIntent.setPendingIntent(pendingIntent);

        Intent intent = new Intent("ch.pas.smslistenerservice.RESEND");
        receiver.onReceive(context, intent);      

        verify(pendingIntent, times(1)).cancel();

        ArgumentCaptor<Intent> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Intent.class);
        verify(context).startService(argument.capture());
        Intent capturedIntent = argument.getValue();
        assertFalse(-1 == capturedIntent.getIntExtra(SMSListenerService.EXTRA_TYPE, -1));
        assertEquals(SMSListenerService.TYPE_RESEND, 
                capturedIntent.getIntExtra(SMSListenerService.EXTRA_TYPE, -1));
    }
}
```

And the shadowed PendingIntent:

```
import org.robolectric.annotation.Implementation;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Implements;

import android.app.PendingIntent;

@Implements(PendingIntent.class)
public class CustomShadowPendingIntent 
    extends org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPendingIntent {
    private static PendingIntent pendingIntentMock;

    public static void setPendingIntent(PendingIntent intent) {
        pendingIntentMock = intent;
    }

    @Implementation
    public static PendingIntent getBroadcast(android.content.Context context, 
            int requestCode, android.content.Intent intent, int flags) {
        return pendingIntentMock;
    }
}
```